# How to add email in Django amin Add user Page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a CustomUser(AbstractUser) Model and in this model I want to add email id field in admin Add User Page.Currently By default first we can enter username and Password and after creating username and password we are redirected to another page where email field is available I want this email field on add User page is this possible.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On admin django already had a `BaseUserAdmin` which is the default, it have 2 parts, add form and change form which both forms created from fieldsets(change form) and add_fieldsets(add form)
To add fields or remove field on add form override the BaseUserAdmin add_fieldsets:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('email',)}),
    )
```

> If you are using a custom ModelAdmin which is a subclass of
> django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin, then you need to add your custom
> fields to fieldsets (for fields to be used in editing users) and to
> add_fieldsets (for fields to be used when creating a user)

second method: override add_fieldsets attribute itself:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
```

Document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin

Comment: Hi @linhNguyen thanks for the answer,But How do I override Below Admin Code.  class           ' CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
       list_display = ('username',)'

Comment: @charanjeetsingh i had updated my answer for a simpler solution

Comment: Getting this error FieldError at /admin/practice/customuser/add/

Unknown field(s) (e, m, i, l, a) specified for CustomUser. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CustomUserAdmin.

Comment: @charanjeetsingh probably some typo i made, i updated the answer again

Comment: Thanks a Lot @linhNguyen its working perfectly now

Comment: @charanjeetsingh good to know, you can accept the answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: Already Did Once again thanks a lot buddy

Comment: @charanjeetsingh no i mean tick the check mark next to the answer so its an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

In `admin.py` of your app, create a [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin) and use the `fields` attribute to include the email field in the view.

**Example:**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')

admin.site.register(CustomUser,CustomUserAdmin)
```